# Hot reload in Electron/React application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

Hot reloading seems to no longer be working. I am not sure what could of changed in my setup, in fact as far as I can tell, and git logs show, nothing was changed.

Regardless, Im trying to get reloading of CSS and Reacts `.jsx` files working.

Currently, I run `npm run watch` followed by `npm run start` in another console tab. The application starts, but any changes in files are not reloaded. My package.json looks like the following:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env ENVIRONMENT=DEV electron main.js",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.19.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.1",
    "electron": "^1.3.4",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.56.13",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.5.0",
    "store": "^1.3.20",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Some unnecessary dependencies are omitted. My `webpack.config.js` looks like the following:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/index.jsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/build/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        { 
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },
        { 
            test: /\.json$/, 
            loader: "json-loader"
        }
    ]
  }    
};
```

What am I missing to get hot reload working in this setup?

**EDIT:** So as you can see, the entry point is defined as `index.jsx`. This file is very simple, and looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styles from './styles.css'
import routes from './router.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Whenever I make a change to this file, the hot reload is triggered. In addition, changes to files that are imported here (like styles.css) are also reloaded. The issue is, all of my components are obviously imported in my router. Any changes to my components therefore are not hot reloaded. How can I get this working properly?

Comment: Are all your JS files with extensions with `jsx`? Your first loader informs to consider the extension of `jsx`. Could update your question?

Comment: Yes, all components have the `.jsx` extensions.

Comment: any use of a component must be capitalized, try it. I know its weird, I have seen it though. routes -> Routes

Answer (score 1):

I use into `webpack.config.js` this options:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  name: 'client',
  entry: './client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        query:
        {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
}
```

And into `package.json` this option:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --inline"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the component doesn't know how to hot reload itself. You can try to add to your `index.jsx`:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

If this doesn't work, I would suggest to rely on `react-hot-loader`.

You'll have to install `webpack-hot-middleware`, and change your `entry` to include it.

```
entry: [
  'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
]
```

Given the fact you're using the `--hot` option, I don't believe you need to add the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`, but I might be wrong.

There's also the v3 of react-hot loader that's coming and that you could look into, but I think it's better for you if you stay on stable releases given you are using Webpack 1.

You can also checkout the full [react-transform-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate) repo, which provide a complete working config for hot-reload with Webpack.

Comment: I tried adding the statement you mentioned  `if (module.hot){}` to my `index.jsx`, but did not see an improvement. I want to emphasize that `index.jsx` and `router.jsx` DO hot reload upon changes, but no other UI components do. Because of this, hot reload should be working, and I assume some configuration is incorrect.

Comment: Oops sorry it was already in your question. That's strange then, is your repo public by any chance? It would be easier to debug. If not, you might want to tryout the [React Hot Loader 3 beta](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/pull/61), I could update my answer if you're interested.

Comment: Its not public, but I can post snippets of code as needed. I would assume the issue would be with one of the config files (webpack.config.js, package.json, etc) rather than any component files.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WebStorm or another editor that supports 'SafeWrite' you may need to disable it.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

"Working with editors/IDEs supporting “safe write”
Note that many editors support “safe write” feature and have it enabled by default, which makes dev server unable to watch files correctly. “Safe write” means changes are not written directly to original file but to temporary one instead, which is renamed and replaces original file when save operation is completed successfully. This behaviour causes file watcher to lose the track because the original file is removed. In order to prevent this issue, you have to disable “safe write” feature in your editor.

VIM - set :set backupcopy=yes (see documentation)
IntelliJ - Settings ▶︎ System Settings ▶︎ Synchronization ▶︎ disable safe write (may differ in various IntelliJ IDEs, but you can still use the search feature)"

Comment: I am currently using Sublime Text. Note that, as stated in the edit of my original post, hot reload is triggered for a select few files, so this is not the issue.

Comment: Take a look at the comments at the bottom of the page I linked. The first one could be it "...Webpack is very picky about the values of the path and filename properties of the output config property...".

Comment: The output path is not the issue, as the application does properly place a bundle in my `/build` directory.

Comment: But it shouldn't. The docs say: "This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your configured output directory. "

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting, `publicPath` is specified in my output config.